# Plural and singular items in the same list

Tags: grammatical-number, lists

Which is correct? The list contains a plural item, but it also contains singular items. So would I use "are" in this sentence?

1. "An applicant with an undergraduate degree in business is supposed to qualify for the one-year program if their grades, resume, and GMAT score **are** good enough."
2. "An applicant with an undergraduate degree in business is supposed to qualify for the one-year program if their grades, resume, and GMAT score **is** good enough."

Comment: What would you say if all in your list are singular items?

Comment: I would use "is."